# No internet Capabilities on Lubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet

I recently wiped the hard drive of one of my old laptops that was gathering dust and decided to try to learn to use Linux. I mounted 17.04 Lubuntu to a usb flash drive and installed it on the Toshiba Satellite A205.

On install, I attempted to connect to wifi, via my internal card, and it would not connect; no matter how many times I tried (laptop sitting inches from modem).

I decided to boot without and connect once everything was installed. Once installed, I found that I was still unable to connect. The WPA2 password is correct and currently being used by 4 other machines. I tried to circumvent this and plug into the modem directly. This also did not work, as I was receiving no connection either way.

I have attempted to manually insert DNS servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 but doing so yields no results and they disappear on reboot.

Any attempt to connect to wireless or wired internet results in the loading animation, followed by a notification that I have been disconnected from the network.

I attempted to follow advice given in another thread to update my Realtek driver, but when I click the .deb file and press "software install" clicking the "install" button does nothing. It shows a click animation but literally yields no results whatsoever.

I have spent the past 7 hours on this and have come up with nothing. Please someone help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have the deb downloaded.

Open a terminal and run:

```
cd /path/to/the/folder/the/deb/is/in
sudo dpkg -i realtek*.deb
```

This is assuming that you do actually need the Realtek driver.

You can't use Software install because of this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1672424.